# Could not open $readmem data file program mem.dat; please make sure the file is added to project and read permission, ignoring [MicroController:44]

Tags: c, microcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBGyO.jpg)When I execute a program that is of microcontroller then complier throws 3 errors:

1. [Synth 8-4445] could not open $readmem data file program mem.dat; please make sure the file is added to the project and has read permission, ignoring [MicroController:44]
2. Synth 8-439] module 'ALU' not found MicroController 47
3. failed synthesizing module 'MicroController MicroController v.21
4. 3 Vivado Tel 4-5] Elaboration failed - please see the console for details Synthesis (3 errors, 1 critical warning

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images. It makes the code unsearchable and you are less likely to receive answers

Comment: Is  mem.dat added to the project?